# AVAudioRecorder Delay 0.2s start end on Device but not on Simulator

Tags: ipad, audio-recording, avaudiorecorder, ios6.1

I'm running this example of how to record with AVAudioRecorder, but when I run it on my device it shows me late start of the recording, and not in the simulator.

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Recording_Audio_on_an_iPhone_with_AVAudioRecorder_(iOS_6)

```
- (IBAction)recordAudio:(id)sender {
if (!_audioRecorder.recording)
{
    NSLog(@"start");
    [_audioRecorder record];
    NSLog(@"end");}
```

}

and log:

```
2013-06-29 03:29:49.877 AVARecorder[6737:907] start
2013-06-29 03:29:50.092 AVARecorder[6737:907] end
```

0.2 delay in my iPad but work fine in Simulator.

I should check to solve this problem?

My device is an iPad with iOS 6.1.3

thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: What do you expect to happen? Actual hardware does have its finite response time. Is it above what is considered normal?

Comment: MasterAM, I need to synchronize MPMoviePlayerController and AVAudioRecorder. for karaoke video app.
The 200 milliseconds produces lag and the lag in the simulator is 5 milliseconds ....As I can control the lag that each device can be different